# Downloaded .AppImage files won't run

Tags: executable, appimage

I have tried to download several applications from .AppImage files but none have run yet. I follow the procedure to open permissions and check the files as executable but when I click on them to launch, nothing happens.

Do the read/write-only or read-write settings affect this? I have tried many combinations, and checked the 'make executable' box but no luck. I also tried the chmod +x Filename.AppImage and that does nothing either.

Have I not installed some crucial piece of software that would affect this ability?

Comment: You need to also enable execution at Files (nautilus) > Preferences > Behavior

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Just setting the executable bit should do the trick. Also try running the appimage on the command line by typing the path of the file (e.g. `~/Downloads/MyProgram.AppImage`. Messages in the terminal may hint about the problem.

Comment: I am using Peppermint 10 on a 32 bit machine.